# Apache Velocity disable template & resource caching

Tags: java, spring-mvc, velocity

I have a Spring Boot application that exposes an API for rendering a relatively simple velocity template. The template uses `#parse` to include a couple of other templates, and otherwise writes out some basic variables passed to it from the Java layer. The templates are inside the JAR file, so they're loaded from the classpath. I use the following velocity engine setup that's created on-the-fly per-request:

```
    VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
    ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
    ve.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
    ve.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.cache", "false");
    ve.setProperty("velocity.engine.resource.manager.cache.enabled", "false");
    ve.setProperty("resource.manager.cache.enabled", "false");
    ve.init();
```

Multiple parts of the template are meant to be unique per-request (the resource is used as the response to a simple Spring MVC controller), so I need to disable caching of the template resources. I have tried the above configuration as-is, as well as defining it in a `velocity.properties` file that's in `src/main/resources`, but changing the template or the files does not "take effect" until I restart the application.

Doing what [this documentation](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#pluggable-resource-manager-and-resource-cache) page says doesn't seem to help (indeed you can see what it does above).

The engine code above is inside a Spring `Component` class and even when moving the `VelocityEngine` stuff to a static final field and just initialising the velocity context each time has not helped.

How can force Spring/Velocity to load templates & included resources each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embarassingly it was because I needed to compile through IntelliJ once changing templates or resources e.g. using Ctrl+F9. Thanks to @Claude Brisson for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

You only need the `classpath.resource.loader.cache` configuration key. And Since all caching in Velocity defaults to false, you don't even need it.

Also, there is no need to re-initialize the VelocityEngine at each request.

I checked with the following little test program that resources where correctly reloaded when modified:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.apache.velocity.VelocityContext;
import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;
import org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeConstants;
import org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader;    

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
            ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
            ve.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
            // next line not needed since 'false' is the default
            // ve.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.cache", "false");
            ve.init();

            VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
            Writer writer = new PrintWriter(System.out);
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (true)
            {
                System.out.print("> ");
                String str = scan.next();
                context.put("foo", str);
                ve.mergeTemplate("test.vm", "UTF-8", context, writer);
                writer.flush();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If it doesn't work in your case, and **especially** if you re-initialize Velocity at each request, then it's certainly a ClassLoader caching problem in Spring itself.

So you should check [Spring Hot Swapping guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html) to see how to disable caching. I guess someone with a better knowledge of Spring can give you a hint on how to proceed in this particular case.

Comment: Are the `VelocityEngine` instances threadsafe? Would a static reference work?

Comment: Yes, Velocity is thread-safe. But contrary to my little example above, the VelocityContext is not and must be re-instanciated.

Comment: Yes, I hold I am now holding a `static final` reference to the `VelocityEngine` instance and creating the `VelocityContext` in the method that merges the templates. Will test & accept shortly. Thank you!

Comment: This hasn't worked, so I'm now investigating whether Spring is stopping loading of class path resources.

Comment: While googling to write my response, I saw that there's a [SmartClassLoader](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/SmartClassLoader.html) interface, which doc says: "_Interface to be implemented by a reloading-aware ClassLoader_". But the Spring Hot Swapping page I pointed out doesn't mention it. I can't help you further with Spring, that may be another question...

Comment: It must be spring. I've moved everything to `/static/` in `src/main/resources/` but still no luck. Have updated with spring details.